# Pandas left join, with duplicated columns

Tags: python, sql, pandas

I have this problem:

A

| ID | Data |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Something |
| 2 | Anything |

B

| ID | A_ID | Data |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | data1 |
| 2 | 1 | data2 |
| 3 | 2 | data3 |

A + B

| ID | Data | B_ID_1 | B_Data | B_ID_2 | B_Data_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Something | 1 | data1 | 2 | data2 |
| 2 | Anything | 3 | data3 | NaN | NaN |

So basically, I want to join two tables, but without duplicating rows and creating new columns.

Comment: Try this, change name of column in 2nd dataframes. Like df2.rename(columns={'Data' :'Data2'}, inplace=True) then merge.. Both dataframes final_df=pd.merge(df1, df2, how='left', on=['ID'])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) for groups, pass to [`DataFrame.pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) and sorting `MultiIndex in columns`, flatten it and last join to `A` by [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
B['g'] = B.groupby('A_ID').cumcount().add(1)

B = B.pivot('A_ID','g').sort_index(axis=1, level=1, sort_remaining=False)
B.columns = B.columns.map(lambda x: f'{x[0]}_{x[1]}')
print (B)
      ID_1 Data_1  ID_2 Data_2
A_ID                          
1      1.0  data1   2.0  data2
2      3.0  data3   NaN    NaN

df = A.join(B, on='ID')
print (df)
   ID       Data  ID_1 Data_1  ID_2 Data_2
0   1  Something   1.0  data1   2.0  data2
1   2   Anything   3.0  data3   NaN    NaN
```